# how to set variable itself as variable value in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How assign a variable value like this in laravel?

```
$gen_jsons = '{"to":"' . $phone . '","message":"' . $message . '"},';
$json_smsdata = "$gen_jsons, $json_smsdata";
```

This code is working in php but I'm getting error in laravel. Error:
`Undefined variable: json_smsdat`

This is the full code in the controller.
I want to send sms using this function. This code is working in php but I don't know why it is not working in laravel controller.

```
public function sendSMS(Request $request)
    {
        $users = User::all();

        foreach ($users as $user) {
            
            $name = $user->name;

            $phone = $user->phone_number;

            $message = rawurlencode("Hi $name, Thanks for using our app!
                                    Regards, Niloy
                                   ");
            $genjsons = '{"to":"' . $phone . '","message":"' . $message . '"}';

            $jsonsmsdata = "$genjsons, $jsonsmsdata";
            $jsonsmsdata = rtrim($jsonsmsdata, ',');
        }

        $smsdata = '[' . $genjsons . ']';

//        echo $smsdata;

         $token = 'asedfasdfasdf';
         $smsdata = $smsdata;

         $url = 'http://api.greenweb.com.bd/api2.php';

         $data = [
             'smsdata' => "$smsdata",
             'token' => "$token"
         ];

         $ch = curl_init();
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
         $smsresult = curl_exec($ch);

//        Result
         echo $smsresult;

//        Error Display
         echo curl_error($ch);

         return redirect('/');
    }
```

How to solve this?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define it like this:

```
$gen_jsons = '{"to":"' . $phone . '","message":"' . $message . '"},';
$json_smsdata = '';
$json_smsdata = "$gen_jsons, $json_smsdata";
```

But as it's a JSON, it's a bad practice. Maybe you need to jsonencode function like this:

```
$gen_jsons = ['to'=>$phone,'message'=>$message];
$json_smsdata[]= $gen_jsons;
$json_smsdata[]= $json_smsdata;
$result = json_encode($json_smsdata);
```

---

Updated:

```
$json_smsdata = [];
foreach ($users as $user) {
    
    $name    = $user->name;
    $phone   = $user->phone_number;
    $message = rawurlencode("Hi $name, Thanks for using our app!
                            Regards, Niloy
                           ");
    $json_smsdata[]= ['to'=>$phone,'message'=>$message];
}

$smsdata = json_encode($json_smsdata);
```

now `$smsdata` is the JSON of sms.

Comment: Thanks  for your answer. I have updated my question. May you please review it?

Comment: @NiloyQuazi check my updated answer, maybe you need to learn https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php